# Argument of '#selector' does not refer to an '@objc' method

Tags: swift4, selector

I created UIButton name is plusButton and UILabel name is itemLabel programmatically and I added target for this button;

```
plusButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(plusButtonClicked(itemLabel)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

@objc func plusButtonClicked(_ sender : UILabel){
   //MY CODE
}
```

I'm getting "Argument of '#selector' does not refer to an '@objc' method, property, or initializer" error. When I remove the parameter in the function there's no any error. But, when it's a parameter in the function I'm getting error.

Comment: You're using the wrong selector name - autocomplete is your friend here.

Answer (score 2):

You have used the wrong selector in your code. The selector should be written like `#selector(plusButtonClicked(_ :)` for your function.

Over all your code should be like this...

```
plusButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(plusButtonClicked(_ :)), for:   UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

@objc func plusButtonClicked(sender:Any) {
    let button = sender as? UIButton
    // you can do whatever want with button.
}
```

Comment: While this might be correct you should really add an explanation about what you have done here to fix this.

Comment: Yeah... but your answer was just code. No explanation of it. Pretend you're talking to humans here. It helps a lot and makes your answer much better.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
@objc func plusButtonClicked(_ sender : UILabel)
                                        ^^^^^^^
```

You cannot send a label as parameter for a button tap. The parameter is the button and you cannot change that.

You cannot work around those rules by trying to change the argument in the selector. Selectors don’t have arguments.

You need some other way to work out which is the right label.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like:

```
plusButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(plusButtonClicked(_ :)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
```

Update it.